# FolderBrowserDialog with MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, directory, folderbrowserdialog

Is there anything like FolderBrowserDialog to be used with MVC 5?I want to be able to press a button eg "Browse" in the browser, get a dialog where I could choose a folder on the server, and get the selected folder path in the controller's action method.
Maybe have a similar function of the package can also tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: folder on the server ? the browser file dialog will usually show the client directory. So if you want to show server directories, you need to write C# code which reads the server directory structure and return to the client. Check `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: Short answer is no. You can use a `<input type="file" />` to select a file, but modern browsers will not send a path for security reasons (and your browser does not have access to paths on the server)

Comment: @Shyju Yes,i want show client directory , but i cannot catch client directory's path.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Uhn...Maybe you know any NuGet can do similar's features?

Comment: Again, browsers **will not** send the path for security reasons.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok...I think I understand what you mean,Thank you for your answer.