# How can i get folder path in asp.net mvc app by browsing folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a ASP.NET mvc app and I have a text box and a button. When I click the button I need to get the browse option so that I can browse all folders in my system, after that if I select the folder, the folder path should be displayed in my Textbox like C:/Users/myFolder/  in textbox.. also when select an UCN path.

I did not find the way to do this !

It would be much appreciated if you can help me on this.
Thanks for replying

Comment: search for FolderBrowserDialog.

Comment: @CodingMytra I'm working on asp.net mvc

Comment: check this ans- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154995/folderbrowserdialog-with-mvc-5

Comment: It is a web application or a windows application?

Comment: Are you looking to browse files on the web server, or on the user's computer? On user computer you can only use a file upload control, and that control will let user select a file, but you only ever get the file name - and for security, you never can get the path names from the local computer - only a file name and a upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET is a web application you can not get your system folder paths. The concept in ASP.NET is to upload the designated file(s) from your system to web server via browse local system. As for folder path if you are developing desktop application using WPF then you can use the .NET FolderBrowserDialog library to browse your system and get the folder path.